# Should redux middleware function cascade be so sophisticated?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-middleware

To define a middleware in redux we need to write a cascade of functions like:

```
const middleware = middlewareApi => next => action => {
    //logic here
}
```

The question is whether this signature is:

- imposed by any necessities / opens any opportunities;
- just the implication of Redux's implementation details / comfortable for developers to manipulate an array of `(next)`-argumented functions like [here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/df770cfc411e272eef35a4194e00551d425f2989/src/applyMiddleware.js#L29-L30)

Could it be replaced with the following signature (with with corresponding changes to Redux's code of course):

```
const middleware = (middlewareApi, next) => action => {
    //logic here
}
```

I realize that the result not totally equivalent to the former one but doesn't seem it makes any difference for the `applyMiddleware` case. The benefit that this syntax is less confusing IMO.

Comment: the current API is more flexible than the one you propose: It gives the middleware author 3 lifetime hooks (when the middleware is bound to redux, when it is added to the MW pipeline, and when a redux action occurs.  This gives more options for defining the scope of any local state the middleware needs

Comment: I call this pattern cheap curry. It provides ultimate flexibility to pass around partially applied functions at the cost of a couple extra parens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a new ["Design Decisions" FAQ](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/faq/DesignDecisions.md) page that answers this.  (The docs have not yet been republished with the new content, so I'm linking the Markdown file.)

As the other comments mentioned already: currying is a standard functional programming technique, and in this case it helps provide closures where a middleware author can store values that need to be accessible across the life of the middleware.

Please see the FAQ entry for links to prior discussions on the topic.